# How to Display image that coming from PHP file with id?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have Image path like `http://sits.in/imageDemo/image.php?image=R171-1.jpg` in data base. 
I can not load image in php by simply putting image link `http://site.in/imageDemo/image.php?image=R171-1.jpg` as src.

My code look like this

```
   <?php
                $count = 1;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


                    ?>
<br>
<br>

                    <div class="card " style="width: 800px; margin-bottom: 25px;">
                        <div class="card-body">


                            <!-- <h5 class="card-title"><b>Product Number : <?php echo $count; ?> </b></h5> -->
                         <p>Order Id : <?php echo $row['orders_id']; ?></p>
                           <p>Product Name : <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></p>



                            <img src="<?php echo $row['image1']; ?>" class="card-img-bottom" alt="Product Image"
                                 style="width: 100px; height:100px">

                        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What happens if you paste http://sits.in/imageDemo/image.php?image=R171-1.jpg in browser? I think you are storing the wrong image path in the database.

Comment: If I hit path `http://sits.in/imageDemo/image.php?image=R171-1.jpg` in chrome, It shows Image.  @BhavikKalariya

Comment: where do you store images?

Comment: It that's the real URL, it doesn't return an image when I try. It returns a HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store path like that in your database

```
http://sits.in/imageDemo/R171-1.jpg
```

Also, create folder imageDemo in your local and store image as R171-1.jpg

Comment: Their URL should work as long as the file returns the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use php file as image you need to make that php file to be shown as image file. Use GD libary. More info about how to use it for jpg here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: No need to use GD to return an image through PHP. Just set the content type header correctly and output the image data.

Comment: Can you tell what to set the content type header. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @MeetPatel - It depends on the file type. For `.jpg`, you can use `image/jpeg`.